# How to store multiple values in shared preference in android?

Tags: android

File name = MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
TextView textView1;
EditText editText1,editText2;
Button button1,button2;
public static final String Default = "NA";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewSignup);        
    textView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Sign_up.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    button1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Login Credentials",MODE_PRIVATE);

            String firstname=preferences.getString("Name",Default );
            String email= preferences.getString("Email",Default );
            String password=preferences.getString("Password", Default);




            if(editText1.getText().toString().equals(firstname)&&
                    editText2.getText().toString().equals(password)){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
            }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();   
        }
    });



}
```

Second file name = Signup.java

public class Sign_up extends MainActivity implements OnClickListener{

```
   public static final String Default = "MyPrefs" ;


  String name,email,password,confirmpassword;
  EditText et1,et2,et3,et4;
  TextView textView;
  Button button;
  SharedPreferences preferences;
  Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);

    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    et4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editConPassword);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewLoginhere);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);


    textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Sign_up.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
//public void sharedPrefarence(){


//}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("Login Credentials", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
    //editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Name", et1.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Email",et2.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Password", et3.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Confirmpassword", et4.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added Successful",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

This code is working but when i add new user then the key is overwrite thats why it is unable to store multiple values so please give me correct suggestion for this

Thanks & Regards 
Rakesh

Comment: the preference system is a key-value dictionary, you assign a value to a key. A key can only have one value.

Answer (score 1):

Shared Preferences only stores simple name/value pairs. They key names are unique, so when you put values for "Name", "Email", "Password", and "Confirmpassword", it will always just overwrite what was there.

It looks like you need multiple sets of these fields, so you might want to store your data in a sqllite db.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the database in order to store multiple records. The preference system is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You need unique key in Shared Prefarence for each unique value. So `onClick` method either you make logic that always save your each user with unique key.

Or another way is that, you can save data in an `ArrayList` and then save that `ArrayList` in `sharedPrefarence` when you done with getting all user info saved in that `ArrayList`. To save  ArrayList is SharedPrefarence check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

And you can also use `sqlite` as well

Answer (score 0):

Here's where i got it done:

[http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/][1]

Much is done in subsection 1.2.2. Look at it keenly.
 You just need to Download and import the Gson Library provided by Google and the trick is done.